# WinUSB Tutorial from MSDN Microsoft

Tags: c++, usb, visual-studio-2015, winusb

I've been faced with problem to follow this tutorial of [Write a Windows desktop app based on the WinUSB template](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn376872(v=vs.85).aspx) from MSDN of Microsoft. Following the instructions, in the step where we need to create an WinUSB Application, the website tell us that **two projects** will be create, but in my application just **one project** is created.

I'm using **Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2015**, and I had installed the **WDK**. **Note:** *I'm using Windows 10 64 bits.*

Below is available the part of the tutorial saying that **two projects** was created:

[image]

Below is available a screenshot of my Solution Explorer:

[image: Solution Explorer from my Visual Studio Community 2015]

Can you help me to figure out what it's happened and help me to solve this?

Comment: The WDK templates are temperamental, you need to use VS2013.  You can report the bug at connect.microsoft.com

Comment: Ok, I'll report this bug. Thanks @HansPassant

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Actually, I'm working on a WinUSB project too. And, it seems like Microsoft split the WinUSB application and the driver package into two different projects.
You should be able to see each of the individual projects when you try to create a new project.

Check the picture below.
The WinUSB INF Driver Package project will contain the INF file you need.

[WinUSB Projects](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZrFP.png)

Comment: Ahah! Under VS2015, "WinUSB INF Driver Package" is found under "Windows Driver > Packages" now. Thank you so much.